# Pointer to two dimensional array

Tags: c, pointers, putchar

Considering the following code:

```
int main()
{
    static char wer[3][4] = {"bag","let","bud"};
    char (*ptr)[4] = wer;

    putchar(*(*(ptr+1)+2));
    putchar(*(wer[1]+2));
    putchar(*(ptr+1)+2);

    return 0;
}
```

the first and second putchar() statement points to the 1st row's 1st element i.e `e` (considering 0 as the base location), whereas in the 3rd putchar() statement, it shows a garbage value.

But as far as the statement says, `(*(ptr+1))` clearly means point to the 2nd row. Why does it happens so? 
Is it due to some `putchar()` norm, or am I complete off the pointer concept?

Comment: `putchar(*(ptr+1)+2);` shouldn't compile, since the parameter is of type `char *`. You should enable strict compliance mode in your compiler settings, it should've yelled at you for that.

Comment: It compiles in gcc and shows garbage `?` @HolyBlackCat

Comment: `note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’`

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi not "it should issue a warning because... they are..." - it shows the warning because they are **not** interconvertible and the code is not legal C, containing a constraint violation.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: But why? `(ptr+1)` only depicts the location

Comment: @mustangDC this is C not assembly. There is *nothing* that "only depicts a location" - every pointer in C is declared in terms of the **type** of the variable it points to.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi it is strictly an error. There is nothing non-strict about it. A C compiler is still allowed to try to make sense of the gibberish it is being fed, it doesn't make the code C though.

Comment: Like, I can still continue to discuss with you and try to understand you even though obviously you don't know what is right or wrong about C. It doesn't prove that you've got a point however ;)

Comment: Just that a C compiler *accepts* a program and compiles it, doesn't mean that the program is indeed written in C. A hosted program that does `#include <stdio.h>` and then `putchar((void*)0 + 'x');` isn't legal C even though some C compiler might compile it with only uttering warnings.

Comment: Also, as a general guidance, `*(ptr+1)` is better written as `ptr[1]`! Then you'd notice that `*(*(ptr+1)+2)` equals `ptr[1][2]`... and knowing that  `&*` cancel each other out, that `*(ptr+1)+2` will equal `&*(*(ptr + 1) + 2)`, and following the other rule, `&ptr[1][2]`

Comment: Without `-pedantic-errors` it's just a warning. As I said initially .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the wrong type to `putchar` in the last line.

Type of `(ptr+1)` is `char (*)[4]`.
Type of `*(ptr+1)` is `char [4]`, which decays to `char*`.
Type of `*(ptr+1)+2` is `char*`.

The pointer gets converted to some strange `int`, which explains the output -- or garbage as you put it more clearly.

When in doubt, it is better to simplify your code than to wonder what's happening.

Using

```
char c = *(ptr+1)+2;
putchar(c);
```

might have revealed the problem sooner.

Comment: Great. When I converted the `char` to `int` I got a location, which is far off the designated indices. Is there any content or article which would explain the pointer complexities better?

Comment: @mustangDC, that's not what's happening. The error is not accessing an array using an out of bounds index. The error is that a pionter gets converted to an `int`, which gets converted to a `char`. I learned by C from the classic -- "The C Programming Language" by K&R.There are other books listed at https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2015/04/5-best-c-programming-books.html.

Comment: Does is significantly mean (*(*ptr+1)+2) = &ptr[1][2], which does not make sense. As mentioned by Anti Hapala in one of the comment.. or just , how should i map the the pointers to exact indices

Comment: @mustangDC, that comment tries to explain why `*(ptr+1)+2` is equal to `&ptr[1][2]`, not `(*(*ptr+1)+2)`. You have to be very careful with the `*`s, the parenthesis, and the `&`s :)